# how to store value in to one data table to another datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 try
    {

        DataTable dtdcnomissing = new DataTable();
        dtdcnomissing.Clear();
        dtdcnomissing = objRetailBAL.DCNOMissing(objRetailPL);
        DataTable dtimport = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtmissingreport = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i <= dtdcnomissing.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {               

            dtmissingreport.Clear();
            objRetailPL.dcnoint = Convert.ToInt32(dtdcnomissing.Rows[i]["id"].ToString());
            dtmissingreport = objRetailBAL.DCNOMissingReport(objRetailPL);
            dtimport = dtmissingreport.Clone();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtmissingreport.Rows)
            {
                dtimport.ImportRow(dr);
            }
        }

        GVDCNoMissingReport.DataSource = dtimport;
        GVDCNoMissingReport.DataBind();


    }
```

I want to store dtmissingreport datatable values into dtimport datatable ...but i am not getting the correct result...How can i store this..

Comment: What is the correct result? and what are the incorrect results you are getting?

Comment: try dtimport.Rows.Add(dr)

Comment: In Dtdcnomissing has 6050 rows and dtmissingReport get every time one row...Now i want to store dtmissingReport values into another datatable dtimport..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this below code..

try
{

DataTable dtdcnomissing = new DataTable();
dtdcnomissing.Clear();
dtdcnomissing = objRetailBAL.DCNOMissing(objRetailPL);
DataTable dtimport = new DataTable();
DataTable dtmissingreport = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i <= dtdcnomissing.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{

dtmissingreport.Clear();
objRetailPL.dcnoint = Convert.ToInt32(dtdcnomissing.Rows[i]["id"].ToString());
dtmissingreport = objRetailBAL.DCNOMissingReport(objRetailPL);
if (dtimport.Rows.Count == 0)
dtimport = dtmissingreport.Clone();
foreach (DataRow dr in dtmissingreport.Rows)
{
dtimport.ImportRow(dr);
}
}

GVDCNoMissingReport.DataSource = dtimport;
GVDCNoMissingReport.DataBind();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Copy() instead of Clone()

```
DataTable dtNew=yourOldDL.Copy();//it will copy data and structure

DataTable dtNew=yourOldDL.Clone();//it will copy structure only
```